# Understanding of Tree fold implementaion

Tags: scala, fold

I am new to scala and I now the basic of it. Due to my internet research I found this [blog](https://blog.adilakhter.com/2015/06/24/inverting-a-binary-tree-with-scala/) post about inverse Btree's. I do understand most of it but this section:

```
def fold[A, B](t:Tree[A] , z:B)(f:(B,A,B) => B): B = t match {
  case EmptyTree => z
  case Node(x,l,r) => f ( fold( l , z )(f) , x , fold( r , z )(f) )
}
```

What does this `(f:(B,A,B) => B)` mean? And also why do I need to enclose it here `f ( fold( l , z )(f) , x , fold( r , z )(f) )` and after the recursion call?

Comment: `f` is a **function** that accepts a triplet of `B, A, B` and returns a new `B`, it represents how to fold a `Node`  given that you already folded both branches _(those are the two `Bs` in the signature)_ plus the element of that node _(the `A`)_.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala, `fold` is generally provided as a shorthand for a "reduce to a single value" expression that would otherwise be accomplished via pattern matching.

For example, [`Option#fold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#fold%5BB%5D(ifEmpty:=%3EB)(f:A=%3EB):B) is essentially

```scala
// in Option[A]
def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B = this match {
  case None => ifEmpty
  case Some(a) => f(a)
}
```

and [`Either#fold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html#fold%5BC%5D(fa:A=%3EC,fb:B=%3EC):C) is essentially

```scala
// in Either[A, B]
def fold[C](fa: A => C, fb: B => C): C = this match {
  case Left(a) => fa(a)
  case Right(b) => fb(b)
}
```

and [`List.foldLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft%5BB%5D(z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) is essentially

```scala
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B) = this match {
  case Nil => z
  case head :: tail => tail.foldLeft(op(z, head))(op) // recursion!
}
```

(disclaimer: I didn't take these from the Scala source, this is just from my own understanding of the methods)

The general goal of a `fold` is to reduce the collection (i.e. Option / Seq/ Either / Tree) to a single value based on the `f` function(s) that you pass to it. The `f` is an anonymous function which typically serves the role of a "transformation for when the value is available" or a "combine next input with previous/recursive result" operation.

In the case of the `Tree` class from the blog post, `Tree` is a recursive data structure, so naturally reducing it to a single value will involve some recursion. That's why you see `fold( l , z )(f)` and `fold( r , z )(f)` inside the `fold` implementation. These are computing the fold results (of type `B`) for the node's left and right sub-trees. Then the `f` is used to combine those results with the node's own value (of type `A`).

It may help to rearrange and rename things:

```scala
def fold[A, B](tree: Tree[A], ifEmpty: B)(combine: (B, A, B) => B): B = t match {
  case EmptyTree => ifEmpty
  case Node(value, left, right) =>
    // recurse into `left` and `right`
    val leftResult = fold(left, ifEmpty)(combine)
    val rightResult = fold(right, ifEmpty)(combine)
    combine(leftResult, value, rightResult)
}
```

In the blog post, the author defined `def size` as an example usage of `fold`:

```scala
def size[T] (tree: Tree[T]) =
  fold(tree, 0: Int){(l,x,r) => l + r + 1}
```

This might make more sense as

```scala
def size[T](tree: Tree[T]): Int =
  fold(tree, 0){ (leftSize, x, rightSize) => leftSize + rightSize + 1 }
```

The conclusion of the blog post uses `B = Tree[A]` in its `fold` call to accomplish the tree inversion. The `combine` (i.e. `f`) function takes the already-inverted left and right sub-trees, and constructs a new Node that puts them in the opposite positions. The `fold` implementation takes care of the recursion and just calls your `f` / `combine` function to piece things together.

Answer (score -1):

The term you're looking for is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), in honor of Haskell Curry.

In Scala, functions can have multiple argument lists. You can think of the declaration

```
def fold[A, B](t:Tree[A] , z:B)(f:(B,A,B) => B): B
```

as being very similar to

```
def fold[A, B](t:Tree[A] , z:B, f:(B,A,B) => B): B
```

It's really just a function of three arguments. But treating it as two separate argument lists confers us several benefits.

## Partial Application

First, some functions are frequently [partially applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) in a certain way. For instance, consider the `const` function, which takes two arguments and returns its first.

```
def const[A, B](a: A, b: B) = a
```

As a function of two arguments, it's basically useless. But it can be useful for creating closures. For instance,

```
{ (b: Any) => const(0, b) }
```

is a function which always returns zero for any input. And since this is the most common way to use this function, we split it into two argument lists.

```
def const[A, B](a: A)(b: B) = a
```

and now we can write `const(0)` to mean "a constant function of one argument that returns 0 unconditionally". It's the same as what we wrote before but much less wordy.

## Implicits

[Implicit parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) (or [using clauses](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/using-clauses.html), as they're called in Scala 3) must have their own argument list. So if a function, say, takes three values and adds them together using a [`Monoid` operation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.scalaz/scalaz_2.13/7.3.6/scalaz/Monoid.html), we would write

```
def add3[A](a: A, b: A, c: A)(implicit m: Monoid[A]) =
  m.append(a, m.append(b, c))
```

And then, when we call the function, we can just pass the three explicit arguments and leave the entire second argument list to implicit resolution.

(Of course, in this *particular* case, [context bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-context-bounds.html) are a shorter way to express the same idea, but that's not always possible)

## Function Arguments

This is the use case most directly applicable to your `fold` function. If we define `fold` as a function of three arguments in one list, we have to call it something like this.

```scala
fold(myTree, myValue, { (b1, a, b2) => ... })
```

Which is not necessarily the most intuitive notation. But if there's an argument list which consists of only one argument, and that one argument is a function, we can omit the parentheses. So with our two-argument form, we can write

```scala
fold(myTree, myValue) {
  (b1, a, b2) => ...
}
```

Notice how it's starting to look more like `if(...) { ... }` or `while(...) { ... }`. We can emulate control constructs with this notation, so it feels more natural in the presence of other Scala code.

We can still *choose* to call the function with two sets of parentheses, as you noted in your recursive call, but when the person who's using our API calls it, they don't *have* to if they just want to provide a lambda that looks like a control block.